# How would I rewrite this funtional view as a generic CreateView in django

Tags: python, django-views

The model for the view is Chapter but it needs to call Book so that the chapter is saved to the right book.

```
def new_chapter(request, book_id):
    """Adds a new chapter"""
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #No data submitted; create a blank form
        form = ChapterForm()

    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data
        form = ChapterForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_chapter = form.save(commit=False)
            new_chapter.book = book
            new_chapter.save()
            return redirect('fallen_worlds:book', book_id=book_id)

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'book': book, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'fallen_worlds/new_chapter.html', context)
```

Comment: Exactly what is not working?

Comment: I made a new app this one with the models Post and Answer but basically the same thing as an earlier website meant for books with the models Book and Chapter in a lot of ways. The problem is this time I used generic views which was fine really easy at the start but then when I made a AnswerCreateView (CreateView) I found that I couldn't save the answers to specific posts like I could save the chapters to their corresponding books  and I have been trying to get the generic view to get the post id from its url like this one does with its book id

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the book in the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse

ChapterCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Chapter
    form_class = ChapterForm
    template_name = 'fallen_worlds/new_chapter.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.book_id = self.kwargs['book_id']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(
            'fallen_worlds:book',
            kwargs={'book_id': self.kwargs['book_id']}
        )
```